# Extension of map $f$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space,$C \subseteq X$ closed and $f:C \rightarrow S^n$ a continuous map.Is it correct to say that there exists an open neighbourhood $U \supseteq C$ in $X$ and a continuous map $F:U \rightarrow S^n$ such that $ F|_C=f$.

I'm wondering if I can use Tietze extension theorem to show it's correct.If so,what would be formal proof then?

Comment: Note that every compact Hausdorff space $X$ is normal([why?](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/compact-hausdorff-normal)), and $C$ is a closed subset of $X$. Now refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2236379/497335).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any extension theorem about $n$-sphere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236379/is-there-any-extension-theorem-about-n-sphere)

Comment: @Bach It is not precisely a duplicate. (1) The other question is much more special (only for ($X = S^n$), although the answer is more general. (2) The OP asks whether there is a proof using  use Tietze extension theorem. This was not the focus of the other question.

Comment: @PaulFrost You are right.

Comment: @Paul Frost Would Urysohn Lemma could also explain this question?

Comment: @XYC I don't see that. The Urysohn Lemma says that two disjoint closed subsets of a normal space can be separated  by a continuous real-valued function, but there is nothing to be separated here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Let $f_i : C \to \mathbb R$ be the coordinate functions of $f : C \to S^n  \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^{n+1}$. By the Tietze extension theorem each $f_i$ has an extension $F_i : X \to \mathbb R$ which gives an extension $F : X \to R^{n+1}$ of $f$. Now let $V = R^{n+1} \setminus \{ 0\}$. There exists a retraction $r : V \to S^n, r(x) = x/\lVert x\rVert$. Then $U = F^{-1}(V)$ is an open neigbourhood of $C$ in $X$ and
$$f ' : U \stackrel{F}{\rightarrow} V \stackrel{r}{\rightarrow} S^n$$
is an extension of $f$.

Note that this works for any normal $X$.